# Android - setRequestedOrientation in DreamService

Tags: android, service, screen, orientation, screensaver

So, we can change screen orientation in an `Activity` with `setRequestedOrientation`, but what to do in a `Service`? My `Service` is a Daydream Service (Screensaver) and I use `setContentView`, how can I change screen orientation in my `Service`?

Comment: Could you be more clear !! what do you mean by service is visual,  android [service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) does not have user interface

Comment: My Service is a Daydream Service (Screen Saver) and don't wanna my Screen Saver rotate when user rotates the device.

Comment: @Bean did you get the solution?